# Фабричный паттерн проектирования на c++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

хотел бы задать вопрос,в прикреплённом ниже коде мне хотелось бы узнать,правильно ли реализован фабричный паттерн проектирования?

```
class Itelevision {
public:
    void virtual showImage() = 0;
    void virtual playAudio() = 0;
};

class Samsung: public Itelevision {
private:
public:
    void playAudio() override {
        cout << "Play audio sucess on Sumsung Tv" << endl;
    }
    void showImage() override {
        cout << "Show image sucess on Sumsung Tv" << endl;
    }
};
class Xiaomi: public Itelevision{
public:
    void playAudio() override {
        cout << "Play audio sucess on XIAOMI Tv" << endl;
    }
    void showImage() override {
        cout << "Show image sucess on XIAOMI Tv" << endl;
    }
};
class Television {
private:
public:
    void showInfo(Itelevision & itelevision) {
        itelevision.playAudio();
        itelevision.showImage();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: ¿И где же здесь фабрика? ¿Что она производит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, не правильно. Ну, т.е., по крайней мере, предложенный код не содержит самого главного - самого [фабричного метода](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/factory-method). В предложенном Вами коде есть 2 возможного продукта фабричного метода - `Samsung` `Xiaomi` с их общим интерфейсом - `Itelevision` - это правильно. Не правильно - отсутствие самого главного - метода, который создавал бы сам продукт. То, что Вы написали, больше похоже на [внедрение зависимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) - `Itelevision` в `Television`.

(Условимся, что, в иллюстративных целях, я буду использовать "сырые" указатели `T*` - для простоты, а вопросы удаления - вообще опущу: в реальной ситуации, вместо "сырых" указателей, наверняка, были бы "умные" - чаще всего `std::unique_ptr<T>`, реже - `std::shared_ptr<T>` или `std::weak_ptr<T>`.)

Первое приближение (это ещё не совсем фабричный метод, т.к. отсутствует run-time полиморфизм производителя продукта; привожу, для понимания сути паттерна - на контрасте со 2м примером непосредственно фабричным методом, приведённым за данным; впрочем, в случае compile-time, данный пример, вполне можно считать фабричным методом: для compile-time, кроме директив препроцессора - как в моём примере ниже - может использовать "шаблонная (template) магия метапрограммирования"):

```
// Можно так (отдельная функция):
Itelevision* createTelevision() {
#if defined(SAMSUNG_IMPLEMENTATION)
   return new Samsung();
#elif defined(XIAOMI_IMPLEMENTATION)
   return new Xiaomi
#else
   return nullptr;
#endif
}

// Или можно так - статическим методом класса
class AnyClass { // Какой-то класс - без разницы какой именно
public:
   Itelevision* createTelevision() { // По сути то же самое, что и в случае с функцией
#if defined(SAMSUNG_IMPLEMENTATION)
      return new Samsung;
#elif defined(XIAOMI_IMPLEMENTATION)
      return new Xiaomi;
#else
      return nullptr;
#endif
   }
};
```

А это уже сам фабричный метод:

```
//Классический вариант:

// Да не смутит тот факт, что, в названии нижеследующих классов,
// фигурирует слово "Factory". В данном случае, они так названы потому, 
// что телевизоры делают на заводах ("Factory"), а не потому, 
// что это паттерн Factory/AbstractFactory.
//
// Абстрактная (или просто Фабрика) это немножко другой паттерн, хотя и,
// во многом, похожий: её главное отличие от фабричного метода - 
// множество связанных между собой продуктов (семейств), 
// подразумевающих совместное использование. 
// Например, если бы расширить данный ("классический вариант") пример 
// (сверх телевизоров) ещё и смартфонами и планшетами соответствующих марок и фабрик,
// то получилась бы вполне абстрактная фабрика.

class ItelevisionFactory {
public:
   virtual Itelevision* createTelevision() = 0;
};
class SamsungFactory : public ItelevisionFactory {
public:
   Itelevision* createTelevision() override {
      return new Samsung;
   }
};
class XiaomiFactory : public ItelevisionFactory {
public:
   Itelevision* createTelevision() override {
      return new Xiaomi;
   }
};

class SomeClass {// Пример использования
public:
   SomeClass(ItelevisionFactory* factory) :
      factory_(factory)
   {}
   void doSomething() {
      // Ещё чего-нибудь ...
      watchTV();
      // Ещё чего-нибудь ...
   }
private:
   void watchTV() { // Соль фабричного метода:
      //какая-то фабрика по производству телевизоров создаёт какой-то телевизор
      auto TV = factory_->createTelevision();
      //мы используем созданный телевизор, без всякого понимания, 
      //что это конкретно за телевизор: нам достаточно знать, 
      //что он (вообще любой телевизор Itelevision) может делать - его интерфейс 
      //(показывать картинку и проигрывать звуки)
      TV .playAudio();
      TV .showImage();
   }
private:
   ItelevisionFactory* factory_;
};

// Вариант со switch-ом:
// Может быть не только свободной функцией (как у меня в данном случае),
// но и статическим методом класса.
// Более того: может комбинироваться с "классическим вариантом" (см. выше), 
// если у Samsung и Xiaomi есть подклассы то, в реализациях их методов,
// будет выбираться конкретная разновидность того или другого по switch-у.
Itelevision* createTelevision(some_enum enumValue) {
   //Заметьте: конкретный тип, возвращённый из данной функции, 
   //всё ещё невозможно угадать на этапе компиляции (compile-time),
   //если, в точке вызова createTelevision(var),
   //конкретное значение var не известно
   switch (enumValue) {
      case some_enum::SomeValueX: return new Samsung;
      case some_enum::SomeValueY: return new Xiaomi;
      default: return nullptr;
   } 
}

struct parse_result {
   // ... Какие-то важные поля результата парсинга чего-либо ...

   Itelevision* TV; // Наш старый знакомый - телевизор

   // ... Ещё какие-то важные поля результата парсинга чего-либо ...
};

parse_result parseSomething(std::istream& in) {
   parse_result result{};
   // ... Что-то как-то парсим ...

   // Внезапно:
   some_enum currentTVType = parseTVType(in);
   result.TV = createTelevision(currentTVType);
   
   // ... Ещё что-то делаем ...
   return result;
}

// Не совсем switch, но его разновидности - тоже варианты фабричного метода.
template<typename T>
class Imapper { 
public:
    // В зависимости от значения какого-то типа T возвращаем телевизор.
    // Какой конкретно? 
    // - Зависит от конкретного типа T и значения его переменной value.
    virtual Itelevision* createTelevision(T value) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class SomeMapper : public Imapper<T> 
public:
    // В реальном мире здесь мог бы быть shared_ptr или weak_ptr
    Itelevision* createTelevision(T value) override {
        auto found_iter = map_.find(value);
        if (found_iter != std::end(map_))
           return &found_iter->second; // В этом отличие от фабричного метода:
        // Возвращается один и тот же объект,
        // что не всегда ОК для фабричного метода, 
        // поэтому данный случай можно как считать, 
        // так и не считать TrueЪ фабричным методом.
        return nullptr;        
    }
protected://может быть и private - как конкретно заполняется map_ я опускаю
   std::unordered_map<T, Itelevision*> map_;
};

// Ещё один фабричный метод:
template<typename T>
class SomeMapper : public Imapper<T>
public:
    // В реальном мире здесь мог бы быть shared_ptr или weak_ptr
    Itelevision* createTelevision(T value) override {
        auto found_iter = map_.find(value);
        if (found_iter != std::end(map_))
           return found_iter->second(); // создаётся ли здесь новый телевизор?
        // - А х.з. - все вопросы к конкретной функции.
        return nullptr;        
    }
protected://может быть и private - как конкретно заполняется map_ я опускаю
   std::unordered_map<T, std::function<Itelevision* ()>> map_;
};

// Десерт: тоже фабричный метод.
class RussianHistoryTimeMachineTelevisionComputer {
public:
    // Количество и типы операндов (параметров) 
    // - "на вкус и цвет" и под задачу.
    // Главное, что метод как-то их использует и в результате... 
    // возвращает какой-то конкретный телевизор
    Itelevision* computeTelevision(int left, int right) override;
};

class Record : public Itelevision { 
// Цветной. Производился в СССР - https://riavrn.ru/projects/color-tv-record/
// и РФ до 2002 года, когда кончились отечественные кинескопы.
public:   
    void playAudio() override {
        cout << "Звучит композиция \"Время вперёд!\"" << endl;
    }
    void showImage() override {
        cout << "По советскому ТВ показывают программу Время" << endl;
    }
};

Itelevision* RussianHistoryTimeMachineTelevisionComputer
::computeTelevision(int left, int right) {

   // В тайне от пользователя класса,
   // из параметров с мутными именами left и right  
   // вычисляется текущий год машины времени и тип телевизора
   // хакерским способом

   int current_year = left; 

   if (current_year < 1922)
       return nullptr; // Не было ещё тогда телевизоров
   if (current_year < 2002)
       return new Record; // Производились отечественные телевизоры до 2002г.

   // Телевизоры стали исключительно импортные. 
   if (right & XiaomyFlag)
       return new Xaomi;
   if (right & SamsungFlag)
       return new Samsung;
   return nullptr;   
}
```

Как можно видеть, "фабричный метод" весьма разнообразен, однако, во всех случаях он подразумевает, что функция/метод возвращает указатель на объект полиморфного типа - т.е. указатель на класс с, по крайней мере, одним виртуальным методом. Конкретные параметры, принимаемые фабричным методом зависят от конкретной задачи, чаще всего фабричный метод не имеет параметров или имеет один параметр, но это не есть правило: главное, чтобы фабричный метод мог на основе параметров выбрать конкретный тип "продукта", который он возвращает. Стоит отметить, что одним из "параметров" для фабричного метода является сам класс объекта, от которого метод вызывается, т.е., отсутствие параметров именно у *метода* класса (а не свободной функции) следствие одного неявного "параметра" - самого объекта определённого класса, от типа/виртуальной таблицы которого зависит какой конкретно метод будет вызван и какой "продукт" возвращён.

В общем виде, фабричный метод это `BasicProduct* create(...)`, где многоточие обозначает какие-нибудь параметры (не в смысле C++, а в смысле самого метода), а `BasicProduct*` указатель на какой-то полиморфный тип, подтипы которого могут возвращаться из фабричного метода.

P.S> На последок, хотел бы порекомендовать сайт, на котором разобраны многие паттерны проектирования, подходы к рефакторингу и т.п. - https://refactoring.guru/ru - хорошо подходит для самообразования в подобных вопросах.

Comment: спасибо за очень подробное и интересное объяснение,буду двигаться дальше))